What flight company is responsible for transferring the baggage during connection?
I took a two-leg flight, the first leg operated by Emirates, the second by FlyDubai. The booking of the entire flight was done via Emirates. I checked-in some suitcases at the origin airport Emirates desk.
When I arrived at my destination, I found out that my checked-in baggage was left at the connection airport. Which company is responsible for this mistake - the first company (Emirates) or the second one (FlyDubai)? This question has two practical implications:

Which company should I sue for compensation?

In case I would like to avoid such mistakes in my following flights, I could potentially go to the company's desk at the connection airport (assuming the layover is sufficiently long), and verify that the baggage was transferred. Which desk should I go to?



Was your luggage lost or just delayed? What was the full itinerary?

Per the Montreal Convention, on an international flight, you can only claim for actual incidental expenses due to a baggage delay. They have 21 days to deliver your baggage before it becomes lost.

Without more details of the exact itinerary it's impossible to say for sure, but was the luggage truly checked through to your final destination?  I believe that on international flights that involve going through customs at the intermediate location (think USA), you have to claim luggage at the intermediate airport, go through customs with your checked luggage in hand, then check your bags again yourself to the final destination.


Which company should I sue for compensation?

Suing seems a little excessive. Lost baggage is a fairly normal event and is governed by the terms and conditions of the marketing carrier that you agreed to when you bought the ticket. In this case that's Emirates; their rules (including compensation) for US passengers can be found here. Most policies are guided by the Montreal Convention.
You will need to file a lost baggage claim at arrival airport of the last leg of your itinerary (even if your bag was lost or destroyed  3 airports earlier). Typically the desk is staffed by the airline that operated this leg or by a 3rd party baggage handler.
You track your claim and negotiate your compensation with Emirates.

In case I would like to avoid such mistakes in my following flights, I could potentially go to the company's desk at the connection airport (assuming the layover is sufficiently long), and verify that the baggage was transferred. Which desk should I go to?

You can't avoid this. Bags are occasionally lost and there is nothing you can do about it. You can walk up to the check-in desk, service desk, or the gate agent, but it's highly unlikely they will give you an answer. Even if they were willing, they often don't have access to the information. Some airlines have automated baggage notification systems, so you get a text every time your bag moves.
If you actually get lucky and have indeed confirmed that your bags have been left behind, then what? Your only choices are to get on the flight or not. If you don't board, you have missed your flight and the rest of your itinerary will be canceled. The only viable option is to get on the plane, file the missing luggage claim at your final destination and take it from there.
I understand that this is frustrating but it's a fact of life in airline travel. I have seen a suitcase of ours being flopped wide open and the distributed contents riding up the luggage belt, I have seen one of my bags left behind right under my window (with the flight attendant giving me a hearty "not my problem" attitude), I had a truck running over a guitar case (obliterating the case but miraculously not the guitar), I saw a bag of mine being broken right at the drop off, etc. These things happen: the only thing you can do is to file a claim at the final arrival airport and go with the flow.
The one thing you want to avoid is having your bag damaged and lost at the same time. Broken bag claims must be filed at the airport so the airline can inspect and document the damage. Of course you can't do that when they lost the bag too and once it finally catches up with you, it's too late to file a damage claim (don't ask me how I know that :-)).
I never check anything mission critical and I rarely check at all. Even if I do, most of the time the bags show up on time and in good shape. Problems happen, but they are rare events.

it gets sillier. My dad once had his luggage end up on the wrong flight, to a different country from where he was going. Airport where his bags ended up noticed the error, loaded the bags on the next flight from there to where my dad was flying to, and he got them with just a few hours delay.

You can avoid the whole issue by traveling with carry-on luggage only. It’s surprising how much you can fit in a ~30l backpack and it also makes getting around your destination much easier.

@Michael: that depends very much on airline rules. The US carriers are very generous with carry on but many other airlines do restrict weight. For example Lufthansa limits at 8kg and for a while they were weighing carry-ons regularly (seems less the case in the moment). 8kg is not a lot of stuff.

@Michael Not always allowed, e.g. if you travel with knives. Sometimes comes with hefty surcharges, e.g. guitar.

True, but your average tourist or business trip traveler should really not need more than a 30l backpack and 8kg. That’s enough for a laptop, several changes of clothes and 2l of water.

@Michael, you obviously haven't traveled with my wife, or tried to pack a week's worth of winter-weather clothes into a backpack.

@Michael Some cheap fares don't allow any carry-ons.

Frankly, I hate the "oh well, there's nothing we can do about it" mindset. This low standard of expectations is exactly why carriers are still not held accountable. If you work in a retail store handling physical inventory, and "lose" as many items as these carriers do, you will be fired before you know what happened. Other industries have developed methods for keeping track of items, so why can't this one?

@Michael let me guess, you're a male, with short hair, and largely interchangeable clothes (eg can wear the same pair of trousers with a different shirt and nobody will notice / comment / judge). As a female long-haired business traveller I tried on ONE occasion to fit everything into carry on and it made my week absolutely miserable. No problem with you doing what works for you, but don't try to claim it "should" work for everyone else.

@Vicky: If anything it should be easier for women because they are shorter and narrower on average, so need less volume and mass for clothes, food, water etc. I’ve never had to bring business dress but I assume with wrinkle-free fabrics you could just cram several shirts into your backpack and possibly even hand-wash and dry them while you are there.

@Mentalist the industry has spend a lot of money on the problem and at large airports the percentage of bags which end up in the wrong place is similar to other highly automated systems. But if you’re handling say 50 million bags a year, 99.9% correct (which is about the right order of magnitude) is still 50,000 bags in the wrong place.

@Mentalist the number of mishandled bags varies between 4 and 8 per thousand. Note that "mishandled" does not mean lost, it includes a lot of other issues like delayed bags (the vast majority), damages, etc. And a lot of effort is put into reducing that.


Which company should I sue for compensation?

Emirates. They've checked in the luggage and promised to have it delivered to you. However at the arrival airport you'll go to the representatives of the airline you flew in with and file a claim with them to have the luggage recovered.

In case I would like to avoid such mistakes in my following flights, I could potentially go to the company's desk at the connection airport (assuming the layover is sufficiently long), and verify that the baggage was transferred. Which desk should I go to?

You'll go to the gate agent of the flight you're taking and confirm with them that the luggage has been loaded on the flight. Some airlines provide luggage tracking function in their apps or websites. However, other than telling you "it hasn't been loaded" I don't know what else they could do.

Expect a standard response along the lines of “of course it has been or will shortly be loaded” regardless of the reality.

and that gate agent won't know whether your bags have been loaded. Especially as quite often, especially on busy airports where aircraft are moved through very quickly, loading of luggage may very well be ongoing while passengers are already boarding. And if you're on a tight connection that becomes even more likely.

I second those comments. Even if the gate agent knew and was willing to share that information, all he can probably tell is that "it's in transfer". I've seen luggage being loaded even after cabin crew announced "boarding completed", or while boarding was in its final stretch. It's highly unlikely one is going to get confirmation of the luggage being loaded before the final boarding call.
